# divide macro in C with zero division check via x86 assembly

Tags: c, x86, inline-assembly

I would like to create division by zero macro as follows:

DIVIDE(zero_exception_boolean, nominator, denominator)

Since I'm not exactly assember guy, could anyone help me achieve this in simple macro which uses x86 assembly (gcc, linux).

From what I remeber, there indeed is 'divide by zero' eflags register that should support this (I may be wrong).

Comment: Do you want to make a macro which divides by zero or a macro which protects against division by zero?

Comment: protects by seting boolean to true if such action is taking place

Comment: Why not do it in C? I like assembly, but here it would be so much simpler not to use it..

Answer (score 2):

There exists no reason why you cannot do this as a C function.

```
div_result_t DIVIDE (int* result, int numerator, int denominator)
{
  if(denominator == 0)
  {
    return div_by_zero;
  }

  *result = numerator / denominator;

  return div_ok;
}


int main()
{
  div_result_t result;
  int value;

  result = DIVIDE (&value, 5, 0);
  if(result == div_by_zero)
  {
    halt_and_catch_fire();
  }
}
```